# curl_init not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the following function that based on cURL

```
$url = "http://www.web_site.com";
$string = @file_get_contents($url);
if(!$string){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');
$string = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

But suddenly my website stopped due to this function and once i remove curl it works fine
so i thought my hosting disabled it so i checked it out

[Click here to check it out](http://www.spyimg.com/info.php)

and it should be working so what is wrong ?

[image]

~ any help , what shall i say to my hosting provider !!

Comment: Whats `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `curl_error()` say? also dont suppress errors.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it does not show any error ! it keeps loading till apeach crash and gives me 500 Internal Server Error !

Comment: it might be because of the line: "$string = curl_exec($ch);"

Comment: @deep that was my hosting provider reply "cURL is already enabled on this server. Here is the path to cURL: /usr/bin/curl" But i do not know what to do !!

Answer (score 0):

The [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) method doesn't look to the URL header, try using cURL with the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` enabled and `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` to the value you prefer.